# Idiomatic way to test for Generic Type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, types

If I can test for basic class types like this in C#:

```
bool stringTest = new string() is string;
// and
bool listOfStringTest = new List<string>() is List<string>;
```

How do I test for List of anything or List 
I know I could use reflection to figure it out, but is there a easier and more idiomatic way to do it in C#?

For example, if I tested `List<int>` or `List<string>` both would return true. And `Nullable<int>` and `DateTime` would return false. Note: just using `List<>` as the example looking for something general purpose.

Comment: `Type.IsGenericType` is were you could start. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/609yztkt(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way to do this is using reflection:

```
Type listType = new List<string>().GetType();
bool isList = listType.IsGenericType && list.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
```

Answer (score 1):

For an exact match, you can use the [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
bool listOfStringTest = new List<string>().GetType().GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
```

As suggested by [Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152602/lee), you have to make sure the type in question is generic to use this method.

Comment: The important part here is the use of an open generic type to do the matching against. `List<string>` is a closed generic type that wouldn't itself compare to `List<>`.

Comment: `GetGenericTypeDefinition` throws an exception if the type is not generic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're after.  If you want to find out if an object is *usable* as a specific type, then I try to use `Type.IsAssignableFrom` where ever I can.  If you're looking to see if an instance is a constructed generic type of an unbound generic type (e.g. constructed generic `List<string>` is a type of unbound generic `List<>`, which seems to be the only case you couldn't do with `is` in your description) then you can do something like this:

```
var type = obj.GetType();
bool b = type.IsGenericType && typeof (List<>).IsAssignableFrom(type.GetGenericTypeDefinition());
```

That tells you, in a hypothetical world where you could declare a variable of type `List<>`, that that variable could be assigned the value of `obj`.

Unfortunately you need the `IsGenericType` check first because some `GetGenericTypeDefintion` implementations thrown an exception if the type is not generic (had they returned `null`, `IsGenericType` would not be needed).